# Retrieving Images form database ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've been working on a project using the adventure works database. The Website it's self is almost complete except for one issue and that's how to handle the varbinary images in the SQL database. I have a Data Access Class that returns the products from the database and a product.cs Class to get/set the values. I've seen tutorials on reading the data but, I would like to have to images in product.cs class but no idea how to properly do it. I've never worked with retrieving Images from a MSSQL database so my knowledge on that is less then perfect.

Here the productDB access class

```
[DataObject]
public class ProductDB
{
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public static List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        string sel = "Select statement goes here"
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sel, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        Product product;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            product = new Product();
            product.ProductID = rdr["ProductID"].ToString();
            product.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
            product.ProductNumber = rdr["ProductNumber"].ToString();
            product.ListPrice = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ListPrice"]);
            product.ProductDescriptionID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ProductDescriptionID"]);
            product.ProductModelID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ProductModelID"]);
            product.Description = rdr["Description"].ToString();

            productList.Add(product);
        }
        rdr.Close();
        return productList;
    }

    private static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
                "AdventureWorks"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

and the product class

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {

    }

    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProductNumber { get; set; }
    public int ListPrice { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int ProductDescriptionID { get; set; }
    public int ProductModelID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you have read so many tutorials why you haven't tried to implement one of them in your code? What's is specifically your problem?

Comment: Reading the image from the SQL database ins't the problem I just want to have something like public string ProductID { get; set; } but for the image. And that were the problem is, I don't know if Images can even be passed to a class like the rest of the values

Comment: You can either use `Image`  class: `public Image Preview { get; set; }` or pass it as `byte[]` and convert to `Image` only when necessary.

Comment: Thank You, that may be what I've been search for.